# Based on user input years, generate random numbers for a 2d array based on the user input

Tags: java, random, input

Before I state my question I have searched the questions that have already been posted and they were of some help to me, but not really what I am looking for.

For now, don't worry about the 2d array portion.

I am supposed to create a program that generates random float values based on the user input for a number of years. Let me explain.

First it asks for the user input for years; the user enters a value between 1-80 and the program checks if the entered value is between those two. (DONE)

Then, based on the user input, it will print out each year with a random value between [0.00 and 100.00] like so.
Example; if user enters 3, then the output will display;

year 1: random values

year 2: random values

year 3: random values

Let's just start with that for now. I already have it to where it it asks for user input and I did have it to where it generated random values, but they were not between what I wanted.

Here is my code so far.

```
package name;
import java.util.*;

public class name {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();

        inputCheck();

    }
    public static void inputCheck(){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the desired number of years: ");
        int years = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        while (years < 1 || years >= 80){
            System.out.print("Please enter a value for years that is greater than 1 and less than 80: ");
            years = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `generator` being used.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();

        int years = inputCheck();
        for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
            System.out.println("Year " + i + ": " + generator.nextFloat() * 100);
        }
    }

    public static int inputCheck() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the desired number of years: ");
        int years = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        while (years < 1 || years >= 80) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a value for years that is greater than 1 and less than 80: ");
            years = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
        return years;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so now I need help with the 2d array. However I don't want have the answer right there. I do want assistance, but just not in the form of "here it is." The other half of it is generating these numbers for a 2d array. So you have years and months. Since a year comprises of 12 months, I need 12 random values per year for however many years are entered.

Comment: You saw the loop for generate the Random value for each year, didnt you?It looped through 1 to the inputted value, and print a random value from 0.00 to 100.00. What you need to create a sub-loop inside that, from 1 to 12 and generate the random value inside that loop.

Comment: Right I see the loop and actually I added that same line in before you replied after thinking about it. But now it needs to generate 12 random numbers for every year entered. So I need another for loop and a 2d array. The problem is I'm not too sure how to do the 2d array portion.

Comment: It is nested loop, outer is from 1 to years, inner is 1 to 12

Comment: So then the inside one would be; for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++){

Comment: Lol, please give it a thought first, I will back to you in 5 min

Comment: int years = inputCheck();
        for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
                System.out.println("Year: " + i + ", month: " + "j with value " + generator.nextFloat() * 100);
        }

Comment: Ok I added in another for loop below the outer one, and used the same generator that was in the outer loop in the inner one. In the inner for loop, I declared a new variable named months so it looks like for (int months=1; months <=12; months++){ then the system print line statement with the generator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that generator being used, but aside from that, when you do you will only get an integer between zero and the given value(without manipulation of course) wha you want is a float between 0 and 100 with two decimal places, so generate the random number:

```
Randint=(Generator.nextFloat(100.00));
```

At least that is what I remember .
I only gave this since you say you have everything else down pat.