# Sorting an array of 12 randomly generated values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random

I am trying to sort an array of randomly generated values but I think I may have this arrays.sort in the wrong place or it does not have the correct syntax.

Could someone explain to me what I need to do to get it to work properly?

Here's the code.

```
package name;

import java.util.*;

public class name {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int years = isValidInput();

        Random generator = new Random();
        float[] monthsArray = new float[12];

        for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++){
            System.out.println("\nYear " + i + ": ");
            for (int months = 1; months <= 12; months++){
                System.out.println("Month " + months + ": " + generator.nextFloat() * 100);
                Arrays.sort(monthsArray);
            }
        }
}

    public static int isValidInput(){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the desired number of years: ");
        int years = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (years <= 1 || years >= 80){
            System.out.print("Please enter a number that is greater than 1 and less than 80: ");
            years = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
        return years;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: So if I put in 3 then it would give me year 1 with 12 months with a random value for each one, then the same thing for year 2 and 3. What I want is for those random values to be sorted in order from least to greatest.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are not actually storing anything in your `monthsArray` variable. You construct it with `new float[12]` but your random numbers are just printed and then thrown away. I suspect you want something like:

```
float[] monthsArray = new float[12];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    monthsArray[i] = generator.nextFloat() * 100;
Arrays.sort(monthsArray);
```

Note that if your are using Java 8 then this can be a lot simpler:

```
double[] monthsArray = Random.doubles(12, 0, 100).sorted().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could condense setting `monthsArray` with a for loop. The Arrays.sort() is in the wrong place and you aren't even using `monthsArray` but generate more random numbers when you print out the months. This should do more of what you are aiming for looking at your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168316/based-on-user-input-years-generate-random-numbers-for-a-2d-array-based-on-the-u): generate random floats for each year, sort them, print them out.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    for(int i=0; i<monthsArray.length; i++)
        monthsArray[i] = generator.nextFloat()*100;
    Arrays.sort(monthsArray);
    System.out.println("\nYear " + i + ": ");
    for(int month = 1; month <= 12; month++){
        System.out.println("Month " + month + ": " + monthsArray[month]);
}
```

To change this to fit your comment:

```
int[][] randFloats = new int[years][12];
int[] monthsArray = new int[12];
for(int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    for(int i=0; i<monthsArray.length; i++)
        monthsArray[i] = generator.nextFloat()*100;
    Arrays.sort(monthsArray);
    for(int i=0; i<monthsArray.length; i++)
        randFloats[year-1][i] = monthsArray[i];
    System.out.println("\nYear " + i + ": ");
    for(int month = 1; month <= 12; month++){
        System.out.println("Month " + month + ": " + monthsArray[month]);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I've been at this nearly all day, so maybe I need to wait until tomorrow and work on it again to clear my mind. But what if I wanted to generate these random values for each month and keep the output as it was in my original post (without adding in the arrays.sort), but then later on in the program I want to sort the random array values to calculate the median, max and min?

Comment: Then you would replace monthsArray[] into a 2d array `int[][] randFloats = new int[years][12];`

Comment: I've added an example implementing the 2d array storing the floats for each year.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work out when I try to run it. It gives me an array out of bounds exception at line 35. I've tried correcting it, but it still gets me the same error. I'll give this another try tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far though!